# wordpress default functions not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a child wordpress theme but I don't know for what reasons at some situations wordpress functions are not working : 
1. like on functions.php -> `is_singular('post_type')` not returning true even if I'm on that post_type post, `is_user_logged_in()` not returning true on few page template that i've created

Comment: You should activate WP_DEBUG in the config file to get more specific error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think is_singular has to be called while using wp_query. I guess you are not using wp_query before calling these functions. This is the implimentation of the core wordpress function.

```
function is_singular( $post_types = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_query ) ) {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false.' ), '3.1' );
        return false;
    }

    return $wp_query->is_singular( $post_types );
}
```